# Simple questions in polynomial rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification

Let $F$ denote a field.

if $f(x) \in F[x]$, show that every nonzero constant polynomial divides $f(x)$.

What I did is the following:

Let $f(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{n} a_{i}x^{i}$ and suppose $c\neq 0$ is a unit in $F$.  Let $g(x)=c^{-1}(\sum_{i=0}^{n} a_{i}x^{i})=\sum_{i=0}^{n} \frac{a_{i}}{c}x^{i}$.  We have $f(x)=cg(x)$ and since c was arbitrary, $f$ is divisible by any constant polynomial.

I know the question is a bit simple.  I am not sure if the way I written it includes all the necessary details.  Can someone could comment on it please. Thank you in advance.

Comment: This looks good to me.

Comment: @Dave thank you for the feedback.